# Uploaded image via code to google cloud storage is available only after refreshing the bucket manually

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, google-cloud-storage

I am uploading image to google cloud storage using python code. Its getting uploaded but it is not available in the cloud storage bucket. If i click the refresh bucket , then its available

```
   from google.cloud import storage

   client = storage.Client()
   bucket = client.bucket(bucket-name)
   blob = bucket.blob('path/name.jpg')
   blob.upload_from_filename(image.jpg)
```

There is no error. But the image is not immediately available in the bucket after i run the code. Its available after i click 'Refresh Bucket' manually

Answer (score 0):

Cloud Storage console does not automatically refresh as the contents of the bucket is changed.  What you're doing now is the correct way to see new changes.

Comment: My cloud function need to use that image once it gets uploaded to the bucket automatically. So the image should be ready available for it to use. I can't manually refresh the bucket everytime so that it can be picked by the cloud function. Is there a way i can achieve it?   Is there a code to refresh the bucket ?

Comment: What the console shows at any given moment in time has no relation to what your Cloud Function is doing. Just because the console doesn't refresh automatically doesn't imply that the object doesn't exist, or your function can't use it.

Comment: So even though the image is not visibly available in the bucket, still my cloud function will be able to pick it?

Comment: The console does not give you a live view of its contents unless you refresh.  That is the purpose of the refresh button.  The new objects don't suddenly exists if you refresh - they were already there before the refresh.